# php date function returns a result I didn't expect

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

In my mysql db I got a timestamp field, the values are:

```
2013-01-30 01:15:00
2013-01-30 01:20:00
```

I use the date function to print it as 24HOUR:MINUTE format but I get a wrong time result.

```
mysql_query('SELECT time FROM locations ORDER BY time ASC');
...
echo "<td>" . date('H:i',$row['time']) . "</td>";
```

The output is: 00:33 for both records, why?

Comment: What is the raw output of $row['time']?

Comment: You mneed to show the loop as well.  Check the data type of `$row['time']`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter for `date()` is a Unix timestamp.

> **Description**
>
> string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
>
> Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using
> the given integer timestamp or the current time if no timestamp is
> given. In other words, timestamp is optional and defaults to the value
> of time().

```
echo "<td>" . date('H:i', strtotime($row['time'])) . "</td>";
```

An alternative solution is to use DateTime:

```
$datetime = new DateTime($row['time']);
echo $datetime->format('H:i');

// or in PHP5.5+
echo (new DateTime($row['time']))->format('H:i');
```

Reference:

- [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
- [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
- [DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)